# How to pass a `where` clause to a function in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a function, `getItems`, and I would like to be able to have multiple `where` to modify the resulting list. I am new to Dart and cannot find the syntax for passing in a `where`.

I tried creating functions with custom `where` to call `getItems`, but cannot due to the `async` nature of `getItems`.

```
  Future<List<IioMenuItem>> getItems() async {

    // ...
    final db = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: true);
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('menu_items');

    final dbFilteredItems = maps.map((item) => IioMenuItem(
      // assign values code removed
    )).where((element) {  // <-- make 'where' replaceable
      if (filterState == FilterState.all) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return element.type.name == filterState.name;
      }
    }).toList(growable: false);

    return List.generate(dbFilteredItems.length, (i) {
      return dbFilteredItems[i];
    });
  }
```

The failed attempt

```
  Future<List<IioMenuItem>> menuItems(FilterState filterState) async {
    final dbFilteredItems = getItems().where((element) { // The method 'where' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. 
      if (filterState == FilterState.all) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return element.type.name == filterState.name;
      }
    }).toList(growable: false);

    return List.generate(dbFilteredItems.length, (i) {
      return dbFilteredItems[i];
    });
  }
```

Can I please get help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you're looking for is a "closure" or "first class function".

See [Functions as first-class objects](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions-as-first-class-objects) on the Language guide.

"A where" isn't a thing. It's not a noun. [`Iterable.where`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) is just the name of a function, and that function happens to take a function as a parameter, and uses it to determine what things to keep.

In this specific case, you want a function that takes a `IioMenuItem`, and returns a boolean that determins where or not to keep it. The type of that is a `bool Function(IioMenuItem)` (see [`Function`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-core/Function-class.html)).

I called it "predicate":

```
Future<List<IioMenuItem>> menuItems(
    FilterState filterState,
    bool Function(IioMenuItem) predicate // <- Take it in as a parameter
) async {
    return (await getItems())
        .where(predicate) // <- pass it along as an argument to `where`
        .toList(growable: false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass any test inside a where.

```
filterItems(Map<String,dynamic> element) {
    if (filterState == FilterState.all) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return element.type.name == filterState.name;
      }
}

final dbFilteredItems = maps.map((item) => IioMenuItem(
      // assign values code removed
    )).where(filterItems).toList(growable: false);
```

2. Use then in future
   `getItems().then((value) => value.where((element ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use `await` to call `async` functions.

```
Future<List<IioMenuItem>> menuItems(FilterState filterState) async {
    final dbFilteredItems = (await getItems()).where((element) { // await has to be used here. 
      if (filterState == FilterState.all) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return element.type.name == filterState.name;
      }
    }).toList(growable: false);
    return dbFilteredItems;
  }
```